# "User Was Removed." What does that mean?

Tags: support, reputation

I seem to have lost 5 reputation over it, but I'm not sure what it means or why it negatively affects me. Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: What, only 5? :P

Comment: I'm like the Scrooge of reputation.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When a user is deleted for any reason (usually either a spammer, or someone requests themselves to have their account deleted) *all* of their votes are deleted with them. This means, that if the user had upvoted you previously, you'll lose that reputation again when he is deleted.

I don't think this behaviour makes sense and [have asked for it to be changed on Meta.SO](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125740/dont-throw-away-all-votes-when-a-user-is-deleted), but it seems to be not easily fixable.

Comment: The behavior makes sense when you consider most of the times someone is deleted it's because they mass spammed. Not saying it should be the default behavior, but it is logical in that light.

Comment: Spammers don't vote, and in cases of vote fraud users are often merged or the votes invalidated directly. The cases where people notice the reputation loss from a deleted user is usually when users request self-deletion, which happens quite regularly.

Comment: I wonder how much reputation was lost when a certain high rep user requested to be deleted a few months ago...

Comment: @bwarner - Should have been none.  Users who ask to be deleted, but have a lot of content, are turned into a "user12345" user so that their content remains.  I believe their votes stick around as well.

Comment: @JasonBerkan no, that's just being deleted. Their votes are still gone, positive scoring posts are just kept.

Comment: So basically since a user gave me 2 upvotes I lost 10 reputation when he was deleted correct?

Comment: Yah, I had this too. Is there a way to figure out who was deleted, just out of curiosity?